# What is the worst-case time complexity for this code?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I had a quiz in my class and didn't do so well on it. I'm looking to find out if someone can explain to me what I did wrong here - our professor is overwhelmed with office hours as we moved online so I thought I'd post here.

```
def functionA(n):
    level = n 
    total = 0
    while level > 1:
        for i in range(0,n):
            level = level // 2
            total = total + i
    return total
```

My answer: The above function is O(log n) because the `for` loop divides the level variable in half on each iteration.

I got 5/10 points but it doesn't really have an explanation as to what was wrong or correct about it. What did I get wrong with this and why?

Image for proof that the quiz was already graded and returned. Just trying to figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

Since `n` and `level` are two totally independent variables that are copies of `n` and `n` never changes, this loop is always O(n).

Once we've established that the inner loop is O(n), we need to figure out the complexity of the outer loop.

On the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop repeatedly sets `level = level // 2`. Since this assignment will quickly reduce `level` down to 1, the outer loop is guaranteed to terminate after its first iteration, making it constant time.

We're left with an overall complexity of O(n) for the single iteration of the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much - that makes complete sense. I'll go ahead and give you the check when the time is met.